# How to add another option to promote an article content to?

Tags: 7

Take a look at my screenshot. [image]

How can I make another option to promote my article contents to? Like promote my content as Affiliate Slideshow or to Slideshow?

Answer (score 0):

form_alter will allow you to add another option

eg

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

     $form['my_field]['#options'][] = array('id' => 'value');

}
```

however, that in itself will not promote it, just allow you to set a value that can be picked up by a view or other means